# Troubles with Laravel and gate facade on apache

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, laravel

I'm trying to set up a laravel application with an apache 2.4.10 (on debian). The laravel application uses the gate facade to manage authorization. The thing is, the pages using gate aren't working as expected, for instance:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth');

    if (Gate::denies('user')) {
        abort(404);
    }
}
```

returns the 404 page....

On another hand, the application recognizes that i am authenticated thanks to the logins stored in the db.

Moreover, the application is working great on Laragon, so it tried to compare the permissions on both apache config but i didn't find any difference.

Here is an extract of the virtual host file i created for the laravel application:

```
    ServerName www.supervision-grolleau.fr
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/******/public"

    <Directory "/var/www/******/public">
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    LogLevel warn
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
```

With my little experience of laravel, i don't think the problem is bounded to .htaccess or anything else but permissions as it is working on Laragon.I would appreciate tremendously help on this topic! Thanks you.

PS: I'm a noob of laravel.

Comment: Is the code you've shown on a namespace? If yes, have you declared a `use` statement for the `Gate` Facade?

Comment: Hi GiamPy, where can i see that? Sorry i didn't write the application ...

Comment: Above the file, do you see a `namespace` statement?

Comment: Sorry yes, there is the "use Gate;" statement among others.